# Vector subscript out of range при работе с большими данными

Tags: c++, c++17

При работе с большой базой данных под конец появляется ошибка

```
Vector subscript out of range
```

Наименований около 100млн.
Формат примерно следующий:

```
filenames[2] - id\rating\tnumberVotes(tt00021321\t7.54\t1981)
filenames[1]
id\ttitleType\tprimaryTitle\toriginalTitle\tisAdult\tstartYear\tendYear\truntimeMinutes genres(tt0000001\tshort\tCarmencita\tCarmencita\t0\t1894\t\N\t1\tDocumentary,Short)
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

```cpp
#include "Help.h"
vector<string> split(string& toSplit) {
    vector<string> vec;
    string word = "";
    for (char c : toSplit) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            if (word == "") {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                vec.push_back(word);
                word = "";
            }
        }
        else {
            word += c;
        }
    }
    vec.push_back(word);
    return vec;
}

//ratings - checkfile, basics - checkFile1
string getId(string& str1, string& str2,string& genre) {
    vector<string> splitOne, splitTwo;
    splitOne = split(str1);
    if (stoi(splitOne[2]) < 1000)return "";
    splitTwo = split(str2);
    if (splitTwo[1] != "short" || stoi(splitTwo[4]) != 0 || splitTwo[8].find(genre) == std::string::npos)
        return "";
    return splitTwo[2];
}
void knowFile(string& fileName, vector<string>& filenames) {
    fstream toCheck;
    string buf;
    toCheck.open(fileName, fstream::in | fstream::out);
    getline(toCheck, buf);
    if (buf.find("titleId")!=std::string::npos)
    {
        filenames[0] = fileName;
        return;
    }
    if (buf.find("isAdult") != std::string::npos) {
        filenames[1] = fileName;
        return;
    }
    if (buf.find("numVotes") != std::string::npos) {
        filenames[2] = fileName;
        return;
    }

    toCheck.close();
}
void bestFilms(vector<string>& files,string& genre) {
    string buf,buf1;
    //ratings - 2,basics - 1
    vector<string> filenames(3);
    for (string s : files) {
        knowFile(s, filenames);
    }
    fstream checkFile, checkFile1,checkFile2;
    checkFile.open(filenames[2], fstream::in | fstream::out);
    checkFile1.open(filenames[1], fstream::in | fstream::out);
    getline(checkFile, buf);
    getline(checkFile1, buf1);
    string id;
    while(!checkFile.eof())
    {
        
        getline(checkFile, buf);
        getline(checkFile1, buf1);
         id = getId(buf, buf1, genre);
        if (id != "")
            cout << id << endl;
    }
    checkFile.close();
    checkFile1.close();
}
```

Comment: Мы бы могли вместе искать где индекс  выходит  за пределы, еслибы в вашем коде была бы хоть какая то логика. Лучше сотрите все,  еще раз задумайтесь что вы хотели делать и что нужно для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код приведен не весь, точно сказать невозможно.
Простейший вариант - замените метод `[]` на метод `.at()` - получите более точную ошибку, т.к. проверяется выход за пределы вектора и выбрасывается исключение, кторое можно обработать.
Но скорее всего ошибка в `getId()`, т.к. там идет обращение по индексу к вектору. Откуда у вас уверенность, что исходные данные абсолютно правильные и размер вектора будет 9 элементов и более для `splitTwo[8]` после работы функции `splitTwo = split(str2);`? Это относится ко всем операциям получения элемента по индексу.

```
string getId(string& str1, string& str2,string& genre) {
    if (splitTwo[1] != "short" || stoi(splitTwo[4]) != 0 || splitTwo[8].find(genre) == std::string::npos)
}
```

Тем более, что в функции `split()` вы пропускаете пустые строки, тем самым изменяя количество элементов в итоговом векторе. Хотя похоже на входе у вас форматированный файл с разделителями, в котором каждая строка содержит точное количество элементов. Только элемент может быть пропущен. Например " 1\t 2\t 3\t" - это строка из 3 элементов. И " 1\t\t 3\t" - это тоже строка из 3 элементов, в которой элемент 2 пропущен. И в результате работы `split()` в обоих случаях должен вернуться вектор из 3 элементов. А у вас во втором случае вернется вектор из 2 элементов.

```
vector<string> split(string& toSplit) {
    for (char c : toSplit) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            if (word == "") {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                vec.push_back(word);
                word = "";
            }
}
```